# WritableArray.size() is always 1 in RN 0.55.4 (Android)

Tags: android, react-native

In Android , I have a native module which use WritableArray like this:

```
public class UploadVideoModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
public WritableArray test=Arguments.createArray();
 UploadCallBack uploadCallBack = new UploadCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void testArray(int i) {
            test.pushString("aa "+i);
            System.out.println("================= wa test ============test:"+test+" ,size:"+test.size());
        } }

@Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_MODULE_NAME;
    }

    public UploadVideoModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        WritableArray wa=Arguments.createArray();
        wa.pushString("aaaaaaaaa");
        wa.pushString("bbbbbbbbb");
        wa.pushString("ccccccccc");
        Log.e(TAG,"======= wa ==========="+wa);
        Log.e(TAG,"======= wa ==========size:"+wa.size());
for (int i =0;i<5;i++){
            uploadCallBack.testArray(i);
        }
    }

 interface UploadCallBack {
        void testArray(int i);
    }
}
```

// ================log result ===================

> E/tvb.react.uploadvideo.UploadVideoModule: ======= wa ===========["aaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbb","ccccccccc"]
>       ======= wa ==========size:3
>
> ================= wa test ============test:["aa 0"] ,size:1
>
> ================= wa test ============test:["aa 0","aa 1"] ,size:1
>
> ================= wa test ============test:["aa 0","aa 1","aa 2"] ,size:1
>
> ================= wa test ============test:["aa 0","aa 1","aa 2","aa 3"] ,size:1
>
> ================= wa test ============test:["aa 0","aa 1","aa 2","aa 3","aa 4"] ,size:1

these result are so strange!!!! Why wa 's size is right，but test is always 1 ?
I found when i run with RN 0.51，all is normal ,and size is right! Unfortunately when run in RN 0.55.4, it's has problem.

> Environment:
>
> OS: macOS 10.13.4
>
> Node: v9.9.0
>
> npm: 5.6.0
>
> Watchman: 4.9.0
>
> Android Studio: 3.1
>
> Packages: (wanted => installed)
>
> "react": "16.3.2",
>
> "react-native": "0.55.4", // from 0.51 =>0.55.4

Steps to Reproduce
copy the above codes, then run in RN 0.51 and 0.55.4, you will find its different!!

Answer (score 0):

fix race condition: `ReadableNativeArray.setUseNativeAccessor(true);`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer, including what the race condition is and why your solution fixes it?